# Block port 25 for a Kvm VM on server

Tags: centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, firewalld, ebtables

I need to know how to block port 25 for a VM on a KVM server using `ebtables` or `firewalld` service .
VM has interface name `viifv3035` on the server and `brctl` shows this:

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces

viifbr0         8000.448a5b847b85       no              eth0
                                                        viifv3035
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't with ebtables,

It handle only level 2 networking (ie ethernet)

See : http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/can.html
      http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/cant.html

You need to use iptables for blocking a TPC port.